# Numpy Array to Networkx-Graph with Edge-Labels

Tags: numpy, networkx, numpy-ndarray

I want to plot a graph of my adjacency matrix. I am doing it like this:

```
my_map = initialize_map(5)
print(f"map:\n{my_map}")
temp = nx.MultiGraph()
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(my_map, parallel_edges=False, create_using=temp) 
a=G.edges(data=True)
nx.draw(G)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos=nx.spring_layout(G))
```

[image: Output]

The problem is with the edge labels. They are at completely wrong places. I also don't like the notation ("weight: ...") but I don't mind that much. I rather like to solve the problem of the wrong position. I don't know where the text output is coming from either.
I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what and I didn't find any documentation about it or a similar problem.

Comment: Yes :) thanks for showing me

Comment: if the answer in the post has helped, consider upvoting it :)